# Why does my basic .Net 7 Razorpage app exit when downloading a file using PhysicalFile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exit

I'm trying to download a simple text file using Visual Studio 2022 and .net 7 in c#. However when the file downloads the app exits. Why is it doing this?

I have created an app using Visual Studio 2022. Not the preview version. I'm using .Net 7 and no authentication. I have created a folder in the "wwwroot" folder called "tempfiles" and within this folder is a text file called "test.txt" with the words "A test file" in it.

I have the following in "Index.cshtml".

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>

    <form method="post" asp-page="/Index">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-page-handler="DownloadFile">Test Download</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

And in the file "Index.cshtml.cs" is.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Basic_Web_App.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger,
            IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _environment = environment;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public IActionResult OnPostDownloadFile()
        {
            const string testFile = "test.txt";
            string rootPath = _environment.WebRootPath + "\\tempfiles\\";

            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, testFile);

            return PhysicalFile(filePath, "text/plain", testFile);
        }
    }
}
```

I run the app and click on the download button. It downloads the file and the browser asks what file name do I want with the suggestion "test.txt". One I select ok. The file is added to my downloads. But the problem is that the app exits. In the console there is no error reported. Just that the app has exited with a -1. Why is the app closing?

Comment: I have placed a copy of the project files in a GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/brianjaikens/File-Download-then-App-Exits/).

Comment: So I have managed to answer my own question. The problem was the browser. I recently switched to Brave. When I specify another browser (Chrome, Duck Duck Go, Firefox) almost anything except Brave. It works just as it should.
So the problem was the way that Brave and Visual Studio 2022 talk to each other. They are not good. So I'm qoing to stick to developing on Chrome. 
Phew!